# Given that conditional probabilities are primitives in Bayesian formalism, is $P(A,B)=P(A|B)P(B)$ a definition of joint distribution?

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional-probability

In *Probabilistic Reasoning For Intelligent Systems* by *Judea Pearl*, section 2.1.1, page 31, it is mentioned that in Bayesian formalism conditional probabilities are not defined in terms of joint distribution like $P(A|B)=\frac{P(A,B)}{P(B)}$.

Rather they are taken as primitives present in our knowledge-base just like $P(B)$, say. In fact, it is the joint distribution which, if at all necessary, is calculated as $P(A,B)=P(A|B)P(B)$.

What then the statement $P(A,B)=P(A|B)P(B)$ denote? - a definition of joint distributions in the Bayesian formalism?

**Edit 1:**
Quoting another portion from the book, *section 2.1.1, page 33* -

> $P(A|B)=\frac{P(A,B)}{P(B)}$  and  $P(B|A)=\frac{P(A,B)}{P(A)}$    (2.14)
>
> ...while the mathematician views conditional probabilities as
> mathematical constructs, as in Eq. (2.14), the Bayes adherent views
> them as primitives of the language and as faithful translations of the
> English expression "..., given that I know A". Accordingly, Eq. (2.14)
> is not a definition but an empirically verifiable relationship between
> English expressions.

**Adding to my original query, what sort of an empirical verification can there be for Eq. 2.14 given above?**

Comment: Sure, why not define it that way?

Comment: @AdrianKeister, I just edited my question, adding some quoted section to it and expanding my query by the last line in bold - "what sort of an empirical verification can there be for Eq. 2.14 given above?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with Bayesian approach, it directly follows from the definition of [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability). There is no "empirical verification" for that, it is a mathematical fact that follows from the definition.

Comment: that's precisely what's avoided in Bayesian formalism - defining conditional probabilities in terms of joint distributions. Looking at conditional probabilities as fundamental to reasoning as $P(A)$ (which are estimated rather than derived), rather than derived quantities. At least that's what is mentioned in the reference I gave in the question. The pdf of the book can be found here - https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.5555/534975

Comment: @AnirbanChakraborty nobody avoids joint distributions in Bayesian setup.

Comment: Not avoiding joint distributions, but avoiding defining conditional distributions in terms of joint distributions. I just edited my question, quoting some portion of the book for reference. Also I expanded my query a bit more. I hope it clarifies the source which inspires me to claim the same.

As for editing the question mid-way, based on our conversation, I thought quoting the portion is essential to elaborate the question. However, I feel the spirit of the questions remains the same. Apologies if that caused any inconvenience.

Comment: I edited my answer. I don't know what kind of answer you are looking for, but this is a simple mathematical consequence of the definition of conditional probability. There is really nothing more to this and it doesn't need any additional proofs, validation, or assumptions.